# Automorphic images of cones in free group

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $F_2$ be the free group with basis $\{a,b\}$, with corresponding word metric $d$. For $x\in F_2$, the *cone* $C(x)$ is $C(x):=\{y\in F_2\mid d(1,y)=d(1,x)+d(x,y)\}$, that is, the set of elements that "start" with $x$. Let $\phi \colon F_2\to F_2$ be the automorphism $a\mapsto ab$, $b\mapsto b$.

My question is, for $C(x)$ a cone as above, what does the image $\phi(C(x))$ look like? Outside the silly case of $x=1$, it's not as simple as just equaling $C(\phi(x))$, since after applying $\phi$ some free cancellation might happen. For example $\phi(C(b))$ contains $\phi(ba^{-1}) = a^{-1}$, and so does not equal $C(\phi(b))=C(b)$. But is $\phi(C(x))$ nonetheless always "close to" $C(\phi(x))$ in some sense?

(What do I mean by "close"? Well, for example something like, "the symmetric difference of $\phi(C(x))$ and $C(\phi(x))$ can be written as a union of at most $N$ cones, for some $N$ not depending on $x$," might be desirable.)

Of course one could ask a similar question about any automorphism $\phi$ of any $F_n$, but, first things first.

Comment: The image $\phi(C(x))$ is $R$-Hausdorff-close to the cone $C(\phi(x))$, where $R$ depends on $\phi$ but not $x$. The same is true for general pairs hyperbolic groups $G$ and their quasi-isometries $\phi: G\to G'$. This is a consequence of the Morse Lemma.

Comment: Just to state the obvious. $C$ also depends on the choice of the word metric $d$, so if we add it to the notation, we get $\phi(C_d(x))=C_{d(\phi^{-1}(-),\phi^{-1}(-))}(\phi(x))$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Ah OK, that's easier than I expected, I'll look into that, thanks.